# Getting NSInternalInconsistencyException in conditional segue in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, segue

I am performing a conditional segue in UIButton Click event listener. My segue is drawn between "pathanViewController" and "dekhunViewController" in storyboard with "pathanToDekhun" identifier. But i am getting NsInternalInconsistencyException as

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

After button click i have performed a external api call and after successful return message, i called the segue with performSegueWithIdentifier. But the segue never happen actually. Below is my code portion in pathanViewController. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
 @IBAction func sendBtnListener(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !self.commentSection.text.isEmpty {
            var submitVoganti = DataSerialization(brandName: self.brandName!, rating: Int(self.sliderStatus.value*5), commentText: self.commentSection.text, anonymous: switchBox.on ? true : false)
            var dataSet = DataSet()
            dataSet.postComment(submitVoganti.toJson(),{
                (id) in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pathanToDekhun", sender: self)
                println(id)
            })
        } else{
            println("Comment field should not be empty")
        }
    }

    //Check whether a segue should be triggered or not
    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "pathanToDekhun" {
            return false
        }
        // by default, transition
        return true
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var dekhunScene = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController
        dekhunScene.keyword = self.brandName
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i am doing wrong is my performSegueWithIdentifier is not called in main queue. Thats why it throws exception. What i am doing now is just editing my code as below -

```
 dataSet.postComment(submitVoganti.toJson(),{
                (id) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pathanToDekhun", sender: self)
                }
                println(id)
            })
```

and comment out "override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" function. Thats it.